# Unable to place unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript

Receiving the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

The error states it is on this code line:
let whosUp = document.querySelector(#whosUp);

What is the unexpected identifier? Am I missing something? My complete function is below. I can include my entire file if necessary.

```js
function whosUpFunc(){
  let whosUp = document.querySelector(#whosUp);
  if (gameOver === true){
  whosUp.innerHTML = ""
  }
  else {whosUp.innerHTML = `Player ${currPlayer}'s turn`
};
}
```

Comment: You made a typo. Need to quote your argument string

Comment: Thank you! The error is gone now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function `document.querySelector` expects a string as an argument. You're passing it `#whosUp`, which is triggering the `SyntaxError`.

```
let whosUp = document.querySelector(#whosUp);
```

Should be

```
let whosUp = document.getElementById('whosUp');
```

Comment: Thank you! I keep forgetting quotes. The error does not appear anymore!